# Multi-line HTML form text safely back to screen and into MySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, text, multiline

I've been learning my way around (the basics of) PHP & MySQL for a while, and I've tweaked/built some stuff I'm pretty pleased with - certainly with thanks to StackOverflow as it's been a fantastic place to learn. I'm pretty stuck at the moment though, so I'm hoping you might be able to point me in the right direction.

I've read all the bold caps about the risks of XSS and SQL injection posed by user input, and I intend to always be cautious. So far, I've tried to take minimal queues from the client, and stick to basic comparisons where possible; but now I'm working on a project which needs to deal with a bunch of text (along with some drop-downs).

So far, I've a test-mule working like this:

1. User sets drop-downs, enters a chunk of text (into textarea), submits form.
2. Handler page echoes form data to the user for confirmation, and populates hidden values of another form on this page, which is submitted with a 'Confirm' button.
3. 'Final' handler performs mysql_query to insert row with processed form data.

Essentially, I'd like to take a `$submittedText` string, and modify it so that malicious input is rendered harmless both for the confirmation preview (echo) and insertion into the MySQL database; but crucially, retaining any line breaks the user innocently entered into the text area.

I've been using:

```
<?php

 $submittedText = $_POST['Text'];    
 $processedText = nl2br(htmlentities($submittedText, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
 echo $processedText;

?>
```

...for my confirmation, and that seems to make safe anything I throw at it, and when I pass the `$processedText` through `mysql_real_escape_string`, I don't get any database nasties; my problem comes when I want to get it back out again...

I figured I could use:

```
$processedOutput = strip_tags($databaseText, '<br>');
```

...This catches any HTML/`<script>` tags, but if there was any `<?php // ?>` in the text read from the database, it's parsed by the preprocessor as it runs through my PHP, which at least produces unexpected results, and might feasibly be used to encapsulate other nasties. Any more success I've had in negating malicious input tends to kill the line breaks.

I'd be eternally grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Many thanks,

Rob.

Comment: Is there a reason you can use two variables? one to hold the escaped string and one to hold the output that is echoed to the user?

Comment: PHP code does not magically run when returned from a database query or sent as page output.

Comment: @immulatin I'm happy to use as many variables as it takes, but I'm not sure I follow what you're suggesting?

Comment: @mario I must admit I was surprised by the behaviour. Would PHP stored in MySQL TEXT being parsed when I read it back indicate insufficient (or too much?) escaping somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

On your confirmation page, use two variables. One to print to the user and the other to submit to the database:

```
$submittedText = $_POST['Text'];    
$processedText = nl2br(htmlentities($submittedText, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$sqltext = mysql_real_escape_string($submittedText);
// use $sqltext to insert into the database
// user $processedText to print to the user on the confirmation page.
```

When you pull the text back out you can format the string again to whatever format you want to print to the user.

Comment: [Apols, return key accident] Ahh! OK, I see. So `mysql_real_escape_string` looks after everything that might pose a direct risk to the database, and I'll use `nl2br` with `htmlentities` (as in the echo) each time I pull it back out to screen?

Comment: It seems like a good solution to me. You certainly don't want to output the escaped string to the user since it will look like garbage to them.

Comment: Hmm. I made a slight tweak to the method you suggested - I printed `$processedText` to the user, and passed `$submittedText` to the hidden form (which is what the user is actually confirming), then did `mysql_real_escape_string` in the final stage (processing the confirm (2nd) form). Somehow I ended up with insufficient escaping, because `<b>Here's a bold line</b>` was truncated in the database to `<b>Here` - I'll go back through all my code. Thanks for your help.